# Can you access parent SKSpriteNode in SKAction runBlock:?

Tags: sprite-kit

How can I access the parent SKNode inside the SKAction's runBlock, like below: I am looking for something to replace MY_PARENT_NODE like parent.

```
[SKAction runBlock:^(void){
    MY_PARENT_NODE.position = CGPointMake(1,1);
}],
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do runAction on the node whose parent you are interested in, it's as simple as:

```
[SKAction runBlock:^(void){
    self.parent.position = CGPointMake(1,1);
}],
```

If you run it on some other node, create a local reference to the parent before the block.

```
SKNode* theActionNodeParent = someSprite.parent;
[SKAction runBlock:^(void){
    theActionNodeParent.position = CGPointMake(1,1);
}],
```

Comment: Very wrong! self refers to MyScene, not the node who owns the the action.

Comment: you didn't say that in your question, so I said "assuming that..." ;)

Comment: So now you know. How do you do it?

Comment: the second example I gave you will work, I mean you're eventually running the actions on the target node, so there you will have access to that node's parent as well.

Answer (score 0):

First give a name to your node like this

```
YOURNODE.name=@"name";
```

Then to change the node position do this

```
[SKAction runBlock:^(void){
    [[self childNodeWithName:@"name"] setPosition:CGPointMake(1, 1)];
}];
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. What if you want this Action to run on 100 different SKSpriteNodes?

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking for a solution to this, the following is working for me on iPhone 4 with iOS 7, iPhone 6 with iOS 8 and Mac OS X 10.10 (Swift language):

```
extension SKAction {

    /** 
    An iOS 7 compatible custom action with a close-to-zero duration (0.0001) which will try to execute
    the block only once per iteration (e.g. for repeated &/or re-used actions).
    */
    class func customAction(block: (SKNode)->()) -> SKAction {
        var shouldRun = true
        return customActionWithDuration(
            0.0001, // if 0 block gets executed multiple times iOS 7, so set >0 and check end time
            actionBlock: {
                node, t in
                /* Custom action with duration executes multiple times over a period of "0 to 1". On 
                iOS 7 even if the duration is set to zero, the block executes multiple times (on 
                iOS 8 this seems to be fixed). */
                if shouldRun {
                    shouldRun = false // don't run again for this iteration of 0.0 through to 0.0001
                    block(node)
                }
                if t > 0.0000999 { // seems spritekit only calls with end-time set one time on iOS 7&8
                    shouldRun = true // reset for repeated &/or re-used actions
                }
        })
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
someNode.runAction(SKAction.customAction({
    someNode in
    if let parent = someNode.parent {
        // do something with parent
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "parent", you mean the sprite that's running the action, you just need a closure variable that references the sprite.

```
func runMyAction(s:SKSpriteNode){
        let myAction = SKAction.sequence([
            // this block "closes over" the s argument
            SKAction.runBlock({
                s.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
                s.color = UIColor.redColor()
            }),
            SKAction.scaleTo(0.10, duration: 1.0),
            SKAction.removeFromParent()

        ])
        s.runAction(myAction)
    }
```